# Memoizing SQL queries

Tags: python, pandas, memoization, joblib

Say I have a function that runs a SQL query and returns a dataframe:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import sqlalchemy

query_string = "select a from table;"

def run_my_query(my_query):
    # username, host, port and database are hard-coded here
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://{username}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(username=username, host=host, port=port, database=database))

    df = psql.read_sql(my_query, engine)
    return df

# Run the query (this is what I want to memoize)
df = run_my_query(my_query)
```

I would like to:

1. Be able to memoize my query above with one cache entry per value of `query_string` (i.e. per query)
2. Be able to force a **cache reset** on demand (e.g. based on some flag), e.g. so that I can update my cache if I think that the database has changed.

How can I do this with [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/), [jug](https://github.com/luispedro/jug)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? [joblib's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html) has an example on that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib) (this example basically pastes itself):

```
>>> from tempfile import mkdtemp
>>> cachedir = mkdtemp()

>>> from joblib import Memory
>>> memory = Memory(cachedir=cachedir, verbose=0)

>>> @memory.cache
... def run_my_query(my_query)
...     ...
...     return df
```

You can clear the cache using `memory.clear()`.

---

Note you could also use `lru_cache` or even "manually" with a simple dict:

```
def run_my_query(my_query, cache={})
    if my_query in cache:
        return cache[my_query]
    ...
    cache[my_query] = df
    return df
```

You *could* clear the cache with `run_my_query.func_defaults[0].clear()` (not sure I'd recommend this though, just thought it was a fun example).

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Is there any way to use this to memoize a sequence of Python statements without having to put them inside of a function first? If the statements modify several variables, it requires quite a bit of work to wrap everything into a function just to memoize the computation.

Comment: memoising using not a valid strategy when mutating variables... perhaps sep question to explain what you're attempting?

Comment: ^may not be a valid strategy