# Selective Re-Memoization of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, joblib

Say I setup memoization with [Joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html#reference-documentation-of-the-memory-class) as follows (using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413946/memoizing-sql-queries)):

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
cachedir = mkdtemp()

from joblib import Memory
memory = Memory(cachedir=cachedir, verbose=0)

@memory.cache
def run_my_query(my_query)
    ...
    return df
```

And say I define a couple of queries, `query_1` and `query_2`, both of them take a long time to run.

I understand that, with the code as it is:

- The **second** call with either query, would use the memoized output, i.e:

  ```
  run_my_query(query_1)
  run_my_query(query_1) # <- Uses cached output

  run_my_query(query_2)
  run_my_query(query_2) # <- Uses cached output
  ```
- I could use `memory.clear()` to delete the entire cache directory

But what if I want to **re-do** the memoization for **only one of the queries** (e.g. `query_2`) without forcing a delete on the other query?

Comment: seems that [`.call`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html#joblib.memory.MemorizedFunc.call) _forces_ the computation. you may want to check if it updates the cache as well.

Comment: @behzad.nouri great pointer! I was hoping for a method like that. I looked for the keyword `force` but didn't find anything. `.call` could be the answer. I will check it.

Comment: @behzad.nouri Looking at the [code](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/memory.py#L665-L682), it seems to call `persist_output` so I think it will do the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the library does not support partial erase of the cache.

You can separate the cache, functino into two pairs:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from joblib import Memory

memory1 = Memory(cachedir=mkdtemp(), verbose=0)
memory2 = Memory(cachedir=mkdtemp(), verbose=0)

@memory1.cache
def run_my_query1()
    # run query_1
    return df

@memory2.cache
def run_my_query2()
    # run query_2
    return df
```

Now, you can selectively clear the cache:

```
memory2.clear()
```

**UPDATE** after seeing behzad.nouri's comment:

You can use `call` method of decorated function. But as you can see in the following example, the return value is different from the normal call. You should take care of it.

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> import joblib
>>> memory = joblib.Memory(cachedir=tempfile.mkdtemp(), verbose=0)
>>> @memory.cache
... def run(x):
...     print('called with {}'.format(x))  # for debug
...     return x
...
>>> run(1)
called with 1
1
>>> run(2)
called with 2
2
>>> run(3)
called with 3
3
>>> run(2)  # Cached
2
>>> run.call(2)  # Force call of the original function
called with 2
(2, {'duration': 0.0011069774627685547, 'input_args': {'x': '2'}})
```

Comment: I am hoping to use run dozens of queries, so this may not scale, but thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: @user815423426, After seeing behzad.nouri's comment, I updated the answer.

Comment: [This comment](https://twitter.com/GaelVaroquaux/status/562735568346689536) from the author adds more light to this.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years, but if your code allows you to refactor into separate functions, you can easily call `func.clear()` to selectively remove that function from the cache.

Example code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from shutil import rmtree

import joblib

cachedir = "joblib-cache"
memory = joblib.Memory(cachedir)


@memory.cache
def foo():
    print("running foo")
    return 42


@memory.cache
def oof():
    print("running oof")
    return 24


def main():
    rmtree(cachedir)

    print(f"{sys.version=}")
    print(f"{joblib.__version__=}")

    print(foo())
    print(oof())
    print()

    print("*" * 20 + " These should now be cached " + "*" * 20)
    print(foo())
    print(oof())
    print()

    foo.clear()
    print("*" * 20 + " `foo` should now be recaculated " + "*" * 20)
    print(foo())
    print(oof())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
sys.version='3.9.6 (default, Jun 30 2021, 10:22:16) \n[GCC 11.1.0]'
joblib.__version__='1.0.1'
________________________________________________________________________________
[Memory] Calling __main__--tmp-tmp.DaQHHlsA2H-clearcache.foo...
foo()
running foo
______________________________________________________________foo - 0.0s, 0.0min
42
________________________________________________________________________________
[Memory] Calling __main__--tmp-tmp.DaQHHlsA2H-clearcache.oof...
oof()
running oof
______________________________________________________________oof - 0.0s, 0.0min
24

******************** These should now be cached ********************
42
24

WARNING:root:[MemorizedFunc(func=<function foo at 0x7f9cd7d8e040>, location=joblib-cache/joblib)]: Clearing function cache identified by __main__--tmp-tmp/DaQHHlsA2H-clearcache/foo
******************** `foo` should now be recaculated ********************
________________________________________________________________________________
[Memory] Calling __main__--tmp-tmp.DaQHHlsA2H-clearcache.foo...
foo()
running foo
______________________________________________________________foo - 0.0s, 0.0min
42
24
```